# Informix datetime selection criteria (between operator)

Tags: datetime, criteria, informix

Is there a way to enter selection criteria on an informix datetime field using the between operator? For example if I enter ADAM:ZOOLANDER in an informix form as selection criteria I will get all values between ADAM and ZOOLANDER. If I enter 2014-08-20 15:55:11:2014-08-20 16:00:00 I get an error in field message.

Answer (score 1):

Show us you SELECT statement and error you got. Show us also exact type of your `datetime` column: is it `DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION` or other?

I have checked that for such type you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table  WHERE entry_date
BETWEEN '2010-11-10 13:23:03' AND '2010-11-10 14:06:36';
```

So you must use `BETWEEN` kayword instead of strange `:` character (you see that this character is used to separate time parts).

Comment: NiklasI get this error can you help me ? ERROR: Extra characters at the end of a datetime or interval.
Error Code: -1264

Query = select * from la_ebestand_t where eingelagert_am between 
'2017-03-11 00:00:00.0' and '2017-03-13 00:00:00.0'

Comment: I think Informix has problem with parsing time with decimal dot after seconds. Try with `2017-03-11 00:00:00` instead of `2017-03-11 00:00:00.0`.

Comment: Wow the answer is from 2014 and you answer me anyway. That worked thank you